# Можно ли в JS прерывать выполнения не только цикла (break), но и всего кода?

Tags: javascript, break

Вот пример, хотелось бы чтобы break полностью заканчивал выполнение кода, а не только цикл.

```
let numb = prompt('введите число');
while(numb <= 100) {
    if (numb === null) {
        break; 
    }
    else {
        alert('попробуй еще разок');
        numb = prompt('введите число');
    }
} 
alert('крут');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

делайте return с пустым значением или false

Answer (score 1):

```js
function a() {
  while (true) {
    console.log("Сработает только 1 раз");
    return;
  }
  alert('этот код не будет вызван');
}

a();
```

При вызове оператора `return` в функции её выполнение прекращается.

Comment: как я понимаю - тут цикл, а не функция, и прервать нужно в цикле, чтобы по выходе из цикла последующие строчки не отработали тоже

Comment: Для этого и нужен return, если его вызвать в while, то функция прервётся

Comment: Добавил пример, цикл бесконечный, но после вызова return он сразу же завершается

Answer (score 1):

Всё легче чем кажется, просто оборачиваем весь код в само выполняемую анонимную функцию ([SEAF](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Self-Executing_Anonymous_Function)), примерно так:

```js
(function() {

  console.log('hello 1')
  console.log('hello 2')

  return
  // последующий код не будет выполнятся

  console.log('hello 3')
  console.log('hello 4')

})()
```

**И на ваш код это никак не повлияет, только разве что таб лишний будет в начале.**

Answer (score 0):

в java есть system.exit. Первое, что нашел по js это выбросить экзепшн свой или для десктопа window.stop

Comment: Здравствуйте! Добро пожаловать на RU Stackoverflow, в нашем сообществе принято писать более [развёрнутые ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), если у вас есть комментарий к вопросу, то вы его можете добавить кнопкой "Добавить комментарий" под вопросом.